# ng-model from Angular bootstrap is undefined in controller

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
        //Here is my methods from controller
    $scope.buttonClick = function (index) {
        if (index == "Topics") {
            $scope.update_cloud($scope.all_cloud_elements[0]);
            console.log($scope.radioModel.value);
        } else if (index == "Person") {
            console.log($scope.radioModel.value);
           $scope.update_cloud($scope.all_cloud_elements[1]);
        } else if (index == "Company") {
            console.log($scope.radioModel);
            $scope.update_cloud($scope.all_cloud_elements[2]);
        } else if (index == "Organization") {
            console.log($scope.radioModel.value);
            $scope.update_cloud($scope.all_cloud_elements[3]);
        } else
            console.log("error");
    };
```

All the console.logs above print undefined in the front end. Printing just the ng-model also doesn't work. I followed documentation from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
This is my HTML where the button exists:

```
            <div class="btn-group">
          <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Topics'" ng-click="buttonClick('Topics');">Topics</label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'People'" ng-click="buttonClick('Person');">People</label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Companies'" ng-click="buttonClick('Company');">Companies</label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Organizations'" ng-click="buttonClick('Organization');">Organizations</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide code in executable format like code in plnkr.co?

Comment: your code doesn't look bad, did the console print any errors ? how about a plunk ?